# Questions marked as duplicates after a successful answer

Tags: discussion

I think this might do a little brain-picking, but why do questions that have received a viable, accepted answer still get marked as duplicates? Here is an example I found:[image: Answered question marked as duplicate]

If the question has been answered successfully, shouldn't we just leave it alone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We shouldn't leave it alone because then it leaves **two different versions of the same thing.** Accepting doesn't really mean anything, except that the OP said that the solution *worked*, and they didn't need any more help. Even if it's accepted, there may be other, better answers to the question that still can be submitted. That may not sound like a big deal with one duplicate question, but if it's a hot topic that has 5-10 different questions that are exactly the same, some might be ignored, and it just adds clutter to the site.

A good analogy (involving Ubuntu :D) would be not submitting a pull request for a patch of Ubuntu, just making people download the patch

If there's a good answer, flag it, and request that a moderator merges the two posts to move the answer(s) to the first thread.